# Parse log4j and Java exception logs

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, log4j

I have logs with errors in the following format:

```
2014-01-30 16:15:04:720 GMT [commandHandler-thread-3] ERROR com.example.Main 123-1234567-1234567 - Something bad happened.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Something bad happened.
        at ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ...
        at ...
        at ...
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at ...
        at ...
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at ...
        at ...
        ... 19 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '123-1234567-1234567-2014-01-31 06:52:11' for key 'PRIMARY'
        at ...
        at ...
        ... 32 more
2014-01-31 06:58:02:933 GMT ...
```

I want to parse it with grep, awk, sed, whatever and produce something like this:

```
<filename> 123-1234567-1234567 - Something bad happened: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '123-1234567-1234567-2014-01-31 06:52:11' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So basically, I want to filter all the ERROR lines and the last 'caused by' line in that group (groups are delimited by the log4j dates). If there is no 'caused by' line, I can simply have

```
<filename> 123-1234567-1234567 - Something bad happened:
```

EDIT: I tried something like this:

```
grep "commandHandler.*ERROR\|^\S*Caused by"
```

but I don't want to get the 'caused by' lines not belonging to that particular exception.

Comment: for a start, you can filter out stacktrace like this: `egrep "ERROR|Caused"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
 awk '
    BEGIN { 
        OFS = "\t"; 
    } 
    function all_fields_from(start) { 
        value = ""; 
        for (i = start; i <= NF; ++i) value = value $i (i == NF ? "" : " "); 
        return value; 
    } 
    {
        if ($0 ~ /commandHandler.*ERROR/) { 
            id = $7; 
            error = all_fields_from(9);
            cause = "";
        } else if (($0 ~ /Caused by/) && (id != "")) { 
            cause = all_fields_from(3); 
        } else if ($0 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/) { 
            if (id != "") { 
                print FILENAME, id, error, cause; 
            } 
            id = ""; 
        }
    }' 
 file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far, still need to remove the "." in "happened." and remove "Caused by:". I have to go soon though, hope it helps so far. Im no AWK guru though!

```
 awk '{ 
 {for (x=1;x<=NF;x++)
    if ($x~"ERROR") {
    f++ 
    {if (c !~ f)  print "<"file">",a,b}
    a=$(x+2)" - "$(x+4)" "$(x+5)" "$(x+6)}
} 
{
   if (match($0,"Caused by:")) 
   b=$0
} 
{c=f;file=FILENAME}}
END {
print "<"file">",a,b}' javalogs* | sed 1d
```